# Simple way to change bar color of Flex DownloadProgressBar component?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, progress-bar

Is there a simple way to change the bar color of the default download progress bar by extending the DownloadProgressBar component besides implementing our own progress bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `drawProgressBar` method, where progress bar drawing is performed, is `private`, you cannot change the colors there. But you can write your own class extending `Sprite` and implementing `IPreloaderDisplay` and copy all the code from `DownloadProgressBar` class. And then just set your own colors in `drawProgressBar` method. And don't forget to set your own preloader as a `preloader` property of `Application`.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `preloaderChromeColor` in the Application tag.  If you want more control, you'll need to create a custom preloader which extends SparkDownloadProgressBar and set backgroundColor in there.